# Query self-referential List relationship to retrieve several level child

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a self referential Adjacency List Relationship, that I created following SqlAlchemy documentation. The model looks like:

```
class Menu(db.Model):
    id          = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    title       = db.Column(db.String(255))
    ordering    = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, default = '1')
    parent_id   = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('menu.id'))
    children    = db.relationship("Menu",
                    cascade="all, delete-orphan",  
                    backref = db.backref('parent', remote_side=[id]),
                    collection_class = attribute_mapped_collection('id'))
```

what I actually want is to have query on that model and get data like:

```
root --+---> child1
       +---> child2 --+--> subchild1
       |              +--> subchild2--+--> and so on,
       |                               +--> and so on, if exists
       +---> child3 --+--> subchild1
                      +--> ...
                      +--> ...
                              +--> ...
```

Would be represented with data such as:

```
id       parent_id     title
---      -------       ----
1        NULL          root
2        1             child1
3        1             child2
4        3             subchild1
5        3             subchild2
7        5             so_on1
8        5             so_on2
6        1             child3
9        6             subchild1
```

How can I query to retrieve data represented as above?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get a tree of Menu items with constant number of queries using `resucrsive=True`, which translates to SQL's `WITH RECURSIVE` (not available on some RDBMS). That may be useful if the tree is big and you want to save some time.

```
# db - SQLA session

# pick a root of the menu tree
root = Menu.query.filter(Menu.parent_id == None).first()

# get ids of all menu items in tree with recursive query
included = db.query(
    Menu.id
).filter(
    Menu.parent_id == root.id
).cte(name="included", recursive=True)

included_alias = aliased(included, name="parent")
menu_alias = aliased(Menu, name="child")

included = included.union_all(
    db.query(
        menu_alias.id
    ).filter(
        menu_alias.parent_id == included_alias.c.id
    )
)

# include the root's id and extract ids from tuples
menu_ids = map(
    lambda _tuple: _tuple[0],
    [(root.id,)] + db.query(included.c.id).distinct().all(),
)

# fetch SQLA models
menus = Menu.query.filter(Menu.id.in_(menu_ids)).all()
```

If you don't need speed, just run DFS or BFS on Menu items using `children` relationship.

Comment: Thank you for your response and help. Your way seems really preofessional . the only thing is that it gives and error **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'** `filter(Menu.parent_id == root.id)`

Comment: It seems that `Menu.query.filter(Menu.parent_id == None).first()` returned `None`, which was assigned as value of `root` - you probably don't have any Menu items without parents in your database (which means you don't have any at all, I hope).

Comment: In fact the problems was that the None statement had be like 'None' `Menu.query.filter(Menu.parent_id == 'None').first()`. I fixed.

Comment: I am sorry to take your time but now it raises another error saying that: `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError
OperationalError: (OperationalError) near "WITH": syntax error u'WITH RECURSIVE included(id) AS \n(SELECT menu.id AS id \nFROM menu \nWHERE menu.parent_id = ? UNION ALL SELECT child.id AS child_id \nFROM menu AS child, included AS parent \nWHERE child.parent_id = parent.id)\n SELECT DISTINCT included.id AS included_id \nFROM included' (1,)` Since I'm new to this environment, I've no idea about it

Comment: I don't think that `'None'` instead of `None` will work - maybe that's what caused syntax error. Another possibility might be that your database server does not support `WITH RECURSIVE` - I've only used it with Postgresql.

Comment: I have checked the documentation and it comes that SqlAlchemy supports recursice [cte(name=None, recursive=False)](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.cte)

Comment: Once again I went through the error list and found out: `db.session.query(included.c.id).distinct().all())`

Comment: Is there a way to do this for all roots, instead of only one? If so, how do you translate it to a collection of python objects?