# How to fix "near 'with': syntax error" in recursive CTE query (flask/sqlalchemy)

Tags: sql, recursion, flask, sqlalchemy, common-table-expression

I'm trying to reproduce [this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html?highlight=cte#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.cte) query found on the SqlAlchemy docs page. After setting up the `Part` class in `models.py`, this is what I have:

```
from app import app, db, models
from models import *

@app.route('/')
def test():
    included_parts = db.session.query(
                    Part.sub_part,
                    Part.part,
                    Part.quantity).\
                        filter(Part.part=="our part").\
                        cte(name="included_parts", recursive=True)

    incl_alias = db.aliased(included_parts, name="pr")
    parts_alias = db.aliased(Part, name="p")
    included_parts = included_parts.union_all(
        db.session.query(
            parts_alias.sub_part,
            parts_alias.part,
            parts_alias.quantity).\
                filter(parts_alias.part==incl_alias.c.sub_part)
        )

    q = db.session.query(
            included_parts.c.sub_part,
            db.func.sum(included_parts.c.quantity).
                label('total_quantity')
        ).\
        group_by(included_parts.c.sub_part).all()

    return 'test complete'
```

But this gives an error:

```
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "WITH": syntax error [SQL: u'WITH RECURSIVE included_parts(sub_part, part, quantity) AS \n(SELECT parts.sub_part AS sub_part, parts.part AS part, parts.quantity AS quantity \nFROM parts \nWHERE parts.part = ? UNION ALL SELECT p.sub_part AS p_sub_part, p.part AS p_part, p.quantity AS p_quantity \nFROM parts AS p, included_parts AS pr \nWHERE p.part = pr.sub_part)\n SELECT included_parts.sub_part AS included_parts_sub_part, sum(included_parts.quantity) AS total_quantity \nFROM included_parts GROUP BY included_parts.sub_part'] [parameters: ('our part',)]
```

The generated query (copy pasted from the error message) looks like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE included_parts(sub_part, part, quantity) AS \n(SELECT parts.sub_part AS sub_part, parts.part AS part, parts.quantity AS quantity \nFROM parts \nWHERE parts.part = ? UNION ALL SELECT p.sub_part AS p_sub_part, p.part AS p_part, p.quantity AS p_quantity \nFROM parts AS p, included_parts AS pr \nWHERE p.part = pr.sub_part)\n SELECT included_parts.sub_part AS included_parts_sub_part, sum(included_parts.quantity) AS total_quantity \nFROM included_parts GROUP BY included_parts.sub_part
```

Formatted (with line breaks in different places for readability):

```
WITH RECURSIVE included_parts(sub_part, part, quantity) AS (
    SELECT parts.sub_part AS sub_part, parts.part AS part, parts.quantity AS quantity 
    FROM parts
    WHERE parts.part = ? 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT p.sub_part AS p_sub_part, p.part AS p_part, p.quantity AS p_quantity
    FROM parts AS p, included_parts AS pr 
    WHERE p.part = pr.sub_part
)
SELECT included_parts.sub_part AS included_parts_sub_part, sum(included_parts.quantity) AS total_quantity 
FROM included_parts 
GROUP BY included_parts.sub_part
```

And, for comparison, here's the pure PostgreSQL query that the sqlalchemy docs [link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html) to:

```
WITH RECURSIVE included_parts(sub_part, part, quantity) AS (
    SELECT sub_part, part, quantity FROM parts WHERE part = 'our_product'
  UNION ALL
    SELECT p.sub_part, p.part, p.quantity
    FROM included_parts pr, parts p
    WHERE p.part = pr.sub_part
  )
SELECT sub_part, SUM(quantity) as total_quantity
FROM included_parts
GROUP BY sub_part
```

The only differences that I can see between the Postgre query (which I assume is supposed to work) and the one that I'm generating are:

1. All the extra "AS" statements (`SELECT parts.sub_part AS sub_part` vs `SELECT sub_part`)
2. Different formatting (generated query has line breaks in weird spots - for example, no line break between `UNION ALL` and `SELECT`)

But, as far as I can tell, neither of those should cause a syntax error...
 I've also tried executing the Postgre query as raw SQL (although SQLAlchemy uses sqlite3, apparently, but still):

```
    query = db.engine.execute(\
    '''WITH RECURSIVE included_parts(sub_part, part, quantity) AS (
SELECT sub_part, part, quantity FROM parts WHERE part = 'our_product'
UNION ALL
SELECT p.sub_part, p.part, p.quantity
FROM included_parts pr, parts p
WHERE p.part = pr.sub_part
)
SELECT sub_part, SUM(quantity) as total_quantity
FROM included_parts
GROUP BY sub_part''').all()
```

But I still get a syntax error.

```
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "WITH": syntax error [SQL: "WITH RECURSIVE included_parts(sub_part, part, quantity) AS (\nSELECT sub_part, part, quantity FROM parts WHERE part = 'our_product'\nUNION ALL\nSELECT p.sub_part, p.part, p.quantity\nFROM included_parts pr, parts p\nWHERE p.part = pr.sub_part\n)\nSELECT sub_part, SUM(quantity) as total_quantity\nFROM included_parts\nGROUP BY sub_part"]
```

I also tried reformatting the generated query and executing it as raw SQL with similar results.

And, finally, I tried writing a query in SQLite and executing it:

```
WITH RECURSIVE included_parts(sub_part, part, quantity) AS (
    SELECT sub_part, part, quantity FROM parts WHERE part="our_product"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT parts.sub_part, parts.part, parts.quantity FROM parts, included_parts WHERE parts.part=included_parts.sub_part
)
SELECT sub_part, SUM(quantity) AS total_quantity
FROM included_parts
GROUP BY sub_part
```

This also throws a syntax error.

At this point, I'm not really sure what to do... it seems like even a `WITH` query with correct syntax will still throw an error. I know that recursive CTE queries are supported in Sqlalchemy, according to the docs and according to this (_http://stackoverflow.com/a/24780445)  answer here. I honestly have no idea why all of these queries are considered to have bad syntax. My python code is practically identical to the example in the docs.

Do I need to install something for `WITH RECURSIVE` to work in SQLAlchemy? Is my syntax actually wrong? Pretty much lost here, any help is appreciated.

(Editing to bump this back to the front page. I wish I could say I've made some progress, but I have literally no idea what to do at this point. Is this a PostgreSQL vs SQLite problem? Does anyone have a working example of what I'm trying to do that I can look at?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're running an older version of sqlite3 (as discussed on #sqlalchemy); you have 3.8.2 and CTE support was added in 3.8.3.

Comment: This worked, thanks! I had to change the config file for pysqlite as seen here (https://github.com/ghaering/pysqlite/issues/60), but once everything was actually installed it worked perfectly.