# sqlite query is not working in ios 8.1 below

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

Below query is not working in ios 8.1 below version.
Its give syntax error "With"

> WITH RECURSIVE dates(category, points,diagonisePoints, date) AS
>   (VALUES('Healthy Weight', '0','0', (select DATE(selectedDate, '+1
>   day') as selectedDate from glanceTable ORDER BY ROWID DESC LIMIT
>   1)),('Healthy Diet', '0','0',(select DATE(selectedDate, '+1 day') as
>   selectedDate from glanceTable ORDER BY ROWID DESC LIMIT
>   1)),('Exercise', '0','0',(select DATE(selectedDate, '+1 day') as
>   selectedDate from glanceTable ORDER BY ROWID DESC LIMIT 1)),('Smoking
>   Cessation', '0','0',(select DATE(selectedDate, '+1 day') as
>   selectedDate from glanceTable ORDER BY ROWID DESC LIMIT 1)) UNION ALL
>   SELECT category, points,diagonisePoints, date(date, '+1 day') FROM
>   dates WHERE date < date('now')) insert into glanceTable SELECT
>   category, points,diagonisePoints, date  as selectDate FROM dates 
>   WHERE date <= date('now')

Same query is working iOS 8.2 above.

Since there is no recursive method in iOS 8.1 supported, sqlite will be at version 3.7.13.

Sqlite3 version are automatically changed based on iOS version changes

So is there any alternative way i need to get my query work in below version?

Your feedback is highly appreicated.

Comment: You have to implement the recursion manually.

Comment: Previously asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40970282/sqlite-query-is-not-working-in-ios-8-0-8-1-and-working-in-ios-8-2

Comment: Also, I doubt at this point that there are many people using iOS 8.0 or 8.1. You'd probably be better off raising your minimum to 8.2.

Comment: @StevenFisher You are correct 100%.  some thing which i got to failed to explain the statistics users for my application user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include sqlite3 in your source instead of dynamically linking it with whatever version is provided by iOS. SQLite provides an [amalgamation version](https://sqlite.org/amalgamation.html) of their source code that combines all source files into a single `sqlite3.c` file making it easier to use.

You can download the amalgamation source from https://sqlite.org/download.html. Grab the files `sqlite3.c` and `sqlite3.h` and add it to your iOS project. Import the SQLite header `#import "sqlite3.h"` and continue using the recursive query.

According to the [changelog](https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html), common table expressions were added in 3.8.3, so grab that or something newer.

Also, remove `libsqlite3` from Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries.

Comment: Its working perfect good.  Is there any constrain in future after adding those classes or any updated comes in future?

Comment: You can ship a newer version of SQLite with the future releases of your app. Older versions of the app will remain at whatever you originally shipped with, but that's no different than with iOS and the problem you ran into with versions prior to 3.8.3.

Comment: you feedback is appreciated its also useful in the computing